# Why in this case DataBinding doesn't work vice versa?

Tags: wpf, 2-way-object-databinding

First one has the desired affect - change text in textbox and the content of the label changes whereas the second one doesn't. Why?

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Label Name="displayText" Content="{Binding ElementName=displayText, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox Name="sourceInfo"/>
    </StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
        <Label Name="displayText"/>
        <TextBox Name="sourceInfo" Text="{Binding ElementName=displayText, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: are you sure that the first snippet is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two work:

```
  <StackPanel>
     <Label Name="displayText2" 
            Content="{Binding ElementName=sourceInfo2, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
     <TextBox Name="sourceInfo2"/>
  </StackPanel>

  <StackPanel>
     <Label Name="displayText"/>
     <TextBox Name="sourceInfo" 
              Text="{Binding ElementName=displayText, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

You need to bind to the correct property on the correct item.  In the top case, you bount the label to its own Content property... oops.

Comment: sorry for my typo, must be watching Wimbledon at the time of asking. What I meant to ask was what you have written out clearly without the UpdateSourceTrigger attrib. Remove it and you will see that upon changing the target textbox text the content of the source label doesn't change. So Default trigger for Source<-Target must be something else. Thx agent-j

Comment: @Vishal, the default event is `Leave`, so when you tab away from the textbox, the binding would take effect.  Your example had no other controls you could tab to, so that's why it didn't seem to work.